# Memory not released by DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Guys I have a simple windows form application in C#. It only has 2 Forms. One form has only one button, while other has a `DataGridView` and one button. Please have a look at the code of both forms :

Code of `Form1`, having one button that shows up `Form2`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void showFrom2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.Show();
    }
}
```

Code of `Form2`, which has a `DataGridView` that is populated by GUID to test 10k rows at a time.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void populateGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(i.ToString());
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
            {
                row[k] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    private void closeForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Dispose();
        this.Close();
    }
```

Now whenever I populate `DataGridView` and then close the `Form2`. The memory is not released. If I keep populating the grid and closing the `Form2` "MULTIPLE" times without closing the whole application, my system runs out of memory (I have 1 gb of RAM). Upon calling `dataGridView1.Dispose();` shouldn't `GarbageCollector` do his job and free the memory?

What I want is that whenever I close the `Form2`, the memory should be freed up in the system.

Note : I am monitoring the memory through `TaskManager` (I know it doesn't display the correct amount of memory consumed but it doesn't matter anyway as I run out of memory if I keep populating the grid. The memory is not being release). I even tried to call `GC.Collect()` on the close button (Which is not a good call and it didn't help either).

Also, I would appreciate if someone could tell me how to monitor the "real" consumption by an app. I read somewhere that you use .Net performance counter. What is that?

P.S. Don't ask why I am populating the grid with 10k rows. I am just doing it for testing purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `GC.Collect()` ever.

GC will be called automatically once your RAM limit is about to be reached by the application but if your application requires more RAM that is accessible to the system, you will have OutOfMemory exception.

Comment: Yes I believe that RAM limit is the cause.

Answer (score -1):

> Upon calling dataGridView1.Dispose(); shouldn't GarbageCollector do his job and free the 
>   memory?

No, one has nothing to do with the other.

- Dispose is for unmanaged ressources (not managed memory, file handles).
- The GC runs when it needs to, not on every minor dispose.

> I even tried to call GC.Collect() on the close button (Which is not a good call and it 
>   didn't help either).

It is an idiotic call, not a good one - it totally mucks up the GC statistics and should never be called outside of VERY specific issue and - debugging.

Grab a memory profiler and find out why. A memory profiler will allow you to see what references keep an object alive, as well as what actally uses the memory. I am sort of betting it is not what you think - and that the error is either not what you think at all, or at least not related to the code you are showing.

General culprits in forms keeping memory alive are missed referenes and events (as events mean the caller has to have a pointer to the called object).

THe code you show is fine.

If you ahve a problem getting a memoryprofiler - I prefer memprofiler (http://memprofiler.com/) - not associated, just satisfied user. They have a 7 day free trial.